# Setting Background Stylesheet to QWidget shows on all controls

Tags: css, qt, qwidget

I have set the following CSS to the QWidget Stylesheet:

```
QWidget { background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #00b7ea, stop: 1 #009ec3); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */ }
```

It works fine, but when I put a button or any other control on the canvas, I get the same background colour included in the elements.

[image]

Can someone help me fix this.

I've tried using a QFrame but I always get a border around the Frame like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you set a style sheet for a `QWidget`, the style sheet is applied to that `QWidget` and the entire child hierarchy of that widget. Since you are using `QWidget` as a selector, the style will be applied to any `QWidget` or `QWidget` **subclass**. A  `QPushButton` is a subclass of `QWidget`, so the style rule is applied to it.

There are many ways you could single out just the main QWidget with a selector. In this case, it might be easiest just to use `.QWidget` which will target only `QWidget`s and not `QWidget` subclasses.

If you end up having other `QWidget`s in the child hierarchy, you can be more selective by identifying the class and `objectName` property using `Classname#objectName`.

You should read [this section](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/stylesheet.html) of the Qt docs for more info.